# Handle Concurrent request for fill Warehouse racks | "inventory last item issue"

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, concurrency

I'm building a something like warehouse management system. I have 1 problem with concurrency.

Goal:

We have X warehouses. Lets say 10 warehouses.
Each warehouse has Y sections. Lets say 3.
Each section has Z cells(boxes). Lets say 300.

We have N clients. Lets say 10.000.

Client can place order to specific warehouse.
For specific section. And reserve any count of cells(boxes).
For specifc date.

Scenario.

Warehouse A has only 10 available cells(boxes) in each section.

100 clients in SAME TIME send HTTP request to reserve 1 cell(box) in each section.

Expected result:

10 clients will get response with status result = reserved.
90 clients will get response with status result = not reserved.

My Approaches

**Approach #1**

*Lock inside code*

I did static variable. And lock for each request.
As result API has queue of 100 requests and each request wait another one.

This approach is work, but:

1. If another client will send request to another warehouse, this request will wait for 100 previous request. <=== As Result we have timeout for most of requests
2. Performance and server resources
3. NOT SCALABILITY. If I will run another instance of this API - this cannot work.

**Approach #2**

*Database lock*

I did RedLock for Redis resource. The resource key build as - WAREHOUSEID_DATE

This approach work, and give me

1. SCALABILITY
2. 2 requests for different warehouses not wait each other.

But I still have:

1. Performance problem

For now each request take about 700ms-850ms.

If I get 100 requests in same time for same warehouse and date:

850 * 100 = 85.000ms => 85seconds ==> 1 min 25 seconds.

So its mean most requests will exit by timeout.

2. Server Resources - will grown fast

**Approach 3:**

*Server less.*

I didn't check this approach, but I believe this approach solve me problem with server resource.

Also instead synchrony operation I can change to asynchronous request and report to client result in callback to his server.

The problem:

How I can resolve the time of operation?

I find in internet approach where I need "undersell" or "oversell"

So if there any solution to avoid "undersell" or "oversell" AND to make this operation really fast?

Comment: For which programming language are you asking this question? It is currently tagged as `java` and `c#`.

Comment: What are the warehouses, sections and cells(boxes)? Are these entries in a single database, or each warehouse is a separate database in a different database server, located in remote countries?

Comment: @Marcono1234 Its doesn`t matter. Lets take c#. Main question is understand what is best approach to solve this issue

Comment: @TheodorZoulias One database.

Comment: Why does it take so much time (700ms-850ms) to serve a single request, if all you have to do is to communicate with one local database?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The question is not why its take so much time. This time include logic for check how much boxes space left, etc. Time I can improve. Lets say the time is 50ms for everything. Now I got 2000 request for same warehouse for same day. Currently if I process those request by Redis lock - its like synchrony operation - and its mean the last (2000/2000) request will processed only after => 1999 * 50 => 99950ms => 1m 39s!!! So the question is about pattern itself. Currently I find good article about CQRS and event sourcing from Microsoft. I will update after I will check this approach

Comment: @Taiki were you able to solve this issue?